# Calling scipy from C extension

Tags: scipy, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I would like to load one of the scipy modules (scipy.linalg) inside a function which is exported from a python extension written in C++, so that I can then call a function from it. It would be best if the user to does not have to load the module in their python program beforehand (so `PyImport_AddModule` is not the solution).
Code using the high level `PyImport_Import` like this

```
pckg_name = PyString_FromString("scipy.linalg");
pckg = PyImport_Import(pckg_name);`
```

works, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966857/embedding-scipy-into-c), except in Python 3.6 it produces a warning message before working.

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py:205: 
ImportWarning: can't resolve package from __spec__ or __package__, 
falling back on __name__ and __path__
return f(*args, **kwds)
```

What does the message mean? Its presence suggests I am not doing this the right way. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I have a similar problem in a large codebase, but I can't seem to find what is causing the error. `python -W error` doesn't seem to affect this warning, nor does it seem I can catch/suppress this with a filter.